# Using MS optimization bundles in extension sections

Tags: bundling

Likely a few folks have seen this code before as a way to get around Sitecore not supporting MVC sections, so we can place CSS and JS in the right place on our page:

```
public static class RazorExtensions {
    public static IHtmlString RenderScripts(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper) {
        List<HelperResult> templates = (from object key in htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Items.Keys
            where key.ToString().StartsWith("_script_")
            select htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Items[key]).OfType<Func<object, HelperResult>>().Select(template => template(null)).ToList();

        foreach (HelperResult template in templates) {
            htmlHelper.ViewContext.Writer.Write(template);
        }

        return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
    }

    public static MvcHtmlString Script(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, Func<object, HelperResult> template) {
        htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Items["_script_" + Guid.NewGuid()] = template;
        return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
    }

    public static IHtmlString RenderStyles(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper) {
        List<HelperResult> templates = (from object key in htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Items.Keys
            where key.ToString().StartsWith("_style_")
            select htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Items[key]).OfType<Func<object, HelperResult>>().Select(template => template(null)).ToList();

        foreach (HelperResult template in templates) {
            htmlHelper.ViewContext.Writer.Write(template);
        }

        return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
    }

    public static MvcHtmlString Style(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, Func<object, HelperResult> template) {
        htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Items["_style_" + Guid.NewGuid()] = template;
        return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is use the MS optimization bundle in here, but the type appears to be incompatible when I use `Styles.Render("")` for example. I tried `Styles.Render("").ToHtmlString()` but it didn't like that either. Has anyone gotten this to work, or have another method that works? I assume nothing changed in Sitecore 9 related to using MVC sections!

Comment: we have bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/someStyles").Include(
                "~/path css 1",
                "~/path css 2", ...) and Styles.RenderFormat("<link href=\"{0}\" rel=\"stylesheet\"/>", "~/bundles/someStyles").

It works fine for us

Comment: Anton, I haven't tried it yet, but that sounds like it'd work. Can you post it as an answer and if it works, I'll check it off so I can give you credit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What we have in Global.asax (could be added to `Initialize` pipeline):

```
BundleTable.Bundles..Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/someStyles").Include(
            "~/path to css 1",
            "~/path to css 3",
            "...."));
```

Then we add bundled styles to layout in a next way:

```
@Styles.RenderFormat("<link href=\"{0}\" rel=\"stylesheet\"/>", "~/bundles/someStyles")
```

It works fine for us